# How to add one second to ISO date time string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, isodate

I have date time string `2016-05-31T00:42:11.578Z` I want to add one second to it so it will look like `2016-05-31T00:42:12.578Z`.
How I can add one second to ISO date, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes:

```
$date = new DateTime("2016-05-31T00:42:11.578Z");
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT1S"));
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that to get the date back with microseconds one have to use `$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u')` format

Comment: thanks for quick response it outputs 2016-05-31T00:42:12.578000 how i can get exact 2016-05-31T00:42:12.578z format

Comment: It isn't pretty, but you can do `$date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.").($date->format("u")/1000)."Z";`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no built-in format string for "milliseconds", just `u` for microseconds. You could probably also use: `substr($date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u"), 0, -3) . "Z"` given the fact that your input date does  not come with microseconds at all (i.e. no rounding issues).